# Is Google using Debian and Apache?

Tags: apache, debian, server

Today, while I was searching, I was suddenly confronted with an error message from Google server, that was a 404 not found error with this contents :

> Not Found The Requested URL /search was not found in this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at www.google.com Port 443 (`notic`)

When I refreshed the page that error message was cleared and I saw the search results.

That error was acquired when google was trying to keep this information hidden.
It's true!? Anyone have any idea?!

Comment: Just because you see that doesn't mean it actually came from google. You could very well be behind a proxy/gateway that itself is running debian, and has absolutely nothing to do with google itself.

Comment: @MarcB tnq dude but I sure I don't use any proxy servers !!!